# While using custom InfoWindow getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, customization, infowindow

I am using a custom InfoWindow in my app. I have two question related to it.

> 1. Is it possible to make multiline snippet in InfoWindow

Say am adding some data lets say I need to show LATTITUDE and LONGITUDE when I click on marker. Normally if u set these values in snippet they appear on same line. I would like to show them on two line. Is that possible

I googled about multiline snippet and couldn't find anything much useful so came up with the idea of customising InfoWindow.

> 2.Below show is my custom InfoWindow  which gives me NullPointerException

Getting exception from try-catch loop. I followed some code I found while googleing but it's not working.

```
 private class MyCustomInfoWindow implements InfoWindowAdapter{


    private View view;

    public MyCustomInfoWindow(){

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker markr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mycustom_infowindow, null);
        TextView marker_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.marker_heading);
        try{

            String m_heading = marker.getId();
            marker_heading.setText(m_heading);

        }
        catch(Exception exx){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getInfoWindow Error is  " + marker_heading.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return view;
    }



}
```

My custom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">    

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/marker_heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    />    

</LinearLayout>
```

Using Google Maps V2

Could someone please tell me where am going wrong .

Comment: For `Is it possible to make multiline snippet in InfoWindow` you can add separate TextView's to show LATTITUDE and LONGITUDE in separate lines or use new line char if you want to show only in on TextView

Comment: About the editing, when someone says `googling` or `googled` there's no reason to change to `google` because it messes up the meaning. Code editing is more approriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
TextView marker_heading = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.marker_heading);
```

to initialize `marker_heading TextView` instance because `TextView` is inside `mycustom_infowindow` layout

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this

```
  TextView marker_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.marker_heading);
```

With

```
  TextView marker_heading = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.marker_heading);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
TextView marker_heading = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.marker_heading);
```

you have to pass your View's object as a refernce to find id for TextView